# How can i create Product Link if click Items Ordered products from Order View

Tags: magento-1.9, link, product-linking

How can i create products link, if i click Items Ordered Products in Order View, its go to products page in website. So, i can i view directly from Order View page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just goto `app/design/adminhtml/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`.

**Then add this code**

```
   if($_item->getProductId()){
    $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $_item->getProductId())
    ->addUrlRewrite();
    if($product_collection->getSize()):
        $product_collection_url = $product_collection->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl();
    endif;

    }
```

Comment: Where i can add this code

Comment: i mean which position ..

Comment: could you pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47912/how-can-i-create-product-link-if-click-items-ordered-products-from-order-view